# Creating nuget based component for ASP.net MVC sites

Tags: asp.net, nuget

I want to create a nuget package to add a set of pages to an asp.net MVC site.

For **example** I have several pre-existing a web sites, with a bunch of business logic, that the client wants a simple blog component added on to them. ( or some other reusable component)
So I want to make a reusable blog component, which I can use nuget to add to each of the sites (with perhaps a little config to set URL paths).

**Is there an existing way of packaging up a small site an adding it to another?**

**What would be the best way to package (and un-pack when restored) that with nuget?**

**Would I need to add something in the area registration, or would it be better to leverage the OWIN pipeline?**

Comment: asp.net mvc version?

Comment: @Arvind This will be for a new project, so 5 I think.

Answer (score 0):

1. The created blog should be isolated as a separate project.
2. In the manage nuget packages for your new **BLOG PORJECT**.
   Install **_CreateNewNuGetPackage** package which can be found in
   this [**link**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CreateNewNuGetPackageFromProjectAfterEachBuild/)
3. Build the project, you will have **.nupkg** of the created component
   in your bin folder

For More information check out step by step implementation [**HERE**](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/raj1979/create-and-push-nuget-package-in-visual-studio-2013/)